# How does one disable Git's HTML help (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, git, console

I installed Github for Windows which comes with the Git command line client, and whenever I forget a switch or something and want to use `--help`, instead of dumping to the console it's launching a browser. Is there a way to ask Git to dump the help to the console (as it does in most Unixen by default) instead of launching a browser?

Comment: curl or wget the file: url and pipe the output through html2txt, do that by making it a script and telling git that script is your web browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Linux systems you could set this with `git config --global help.format <web|man|info>`. Unfortunately the man pages are not part of the Git for Windows bundle so only 'web' works.

Answer (score 10):

In windows

```
git <command> -h
```

will write help to the terminal output

```
git <command> --help
```

will pop up a browser window

Answer (score 6):

This is a frail workaround, but if you just want a quick usage summary, feed the git sub-command of your choice a deliberately bad option name. I tried "--halp". For example:

```
$ git stash --halp
error: unknown option for 'stash save': --halp
       To provide a message, use git stash save -- '--halp'
usage: git core\git-stash list [<options>]
   or: git core\git-stash show [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash drop [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash ( pop | apply ) [--index] [-q|--quiet] [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash branch <branchname> [<stash>]
   or: git core\git-stash [save [--patch] [-k|--[no-]keep-index] [-q|--quiet]
                       [-u|--include-untracked] [-a|--all] [<message>]]
   or: git core\git-stash clear
```

I can't say for sure that "halp" will always be rejected, but it seems to get the job done. Hopefully it'll never get interpreted as a usable parameter. This is probably better than random typing, for example, since you might randomly type in correct input.

Comment: This is no different from the output you get if you use the short help switch: `git stash -h` -- short help is always just printed to the terminal.